# Nested Dictionary - Targeting Individual Keys

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I appreciate there are lots of this type of question around here but I've not been able to find a feasible answer.

Put simply, I need to get an array of Prices for all products within a chosen category.

Here is my pList:

```
<key>Product Category</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Product 1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Image</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Large Image</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Detail</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Price</key>
            <integer>100</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>Product 2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Image</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Large Image</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Detail</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Price</key>
            <integer>200</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I have no idea how to target deep within a hierarchy like this. Here is my attempt so far:

```
NSString *detailPListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"detail" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *detailDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:detailPListPath];
currentDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id object in [detailDictionary objectForKey:indication]) {
    [currentDetail addObject:object];
}
```

But then `currentDetail` just shows Product 1, Product 2 etc.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> currentDetail just shows
>   Product 1, Product 2 etc.

Since fast enumeration of a `NSDictionary` iterates over the keys, you are adding the keys to the array. Hence, your output shows Product 1, Product 2, etc.

> I need to get an array of Prices for
>   all products within a chosen category.

You need to use these keys (Product 1, Product 2, etc.) to retrieve the associated product dictionary and then retrieve the value associated with the Price key:

```
NSDictionary *detailDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"detail" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSDictionary *categoryDict = [detailDict objectForKey:@"Product Category"];
NSMutableArray *pricesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[categoryDict count]];
for (NSString *key in categoryDict) {
    [pricesArray addObject:[[categoryDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"Price"]];
}
```

Bear in mind that the resulting `pricesArray` is in **no specific order**.

Comment: You didn't just show me a solution, you taught me a lot about how to access deep dictionaries. Cheers mate, your a lifesaver!